# jQuery - on() function when a div is clicked, but not when a child of that div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one large rectangular parent div inside which there are many child divs. I have an on(click) function that runs when the parent div is clicked, but by default it also runs when anything within the parent div is clicked (including the children).

However, I don't want the on(click) function to run when one specific child of the parent is clicked. How do I make a selector that selects the parent div and everything in it apart from this one child?

Thanks

```
<div class="box"">

<div class="overlay"><div id="text"></div></div>
<div class="slide">
    <div class="slideleft"></div>
    <div class="slideright">
        <span class="upvote">Upvote</span>
        <span class="counter"></span>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Now, this is all within the 'box' div and you can see a demo of what happens [here](http://www.confide.re/confide). If you click the upvote button after having already clicked on a box, then the thing slides back down which I don't want it to. This is the code I'm trying to use right now for this but it's not working:

```
$("body").on("click", ".box", function(e){
        if(e.target.class == 'upvote') {
            return false;
        } else {
                $(this).children('.slide').slideToggle(150);
                $(this).children('overlay').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
            }
});
```

Comment: Consider posting your code here, It's much simpler to help you then. But for your question, check out the :not selector...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdMCJ/1/)

```
$("body").on("click", ".box", function (e) {
if (e.target.className != 'upvote') {
  $(this).children('.slide').slideToggle(150);
  $(this).children('.overlay').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your fiddle was exactly what I was looking for! However, it doesn't seem to be working on my code (added to OP), would you mind taking a look at it for me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this :

```
$('.child').on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yU8Fa/3/)**

Comment: Why bind a second handler just to prevent it?

Comment: Alternative to previous answer.