# On Click on td, Textbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - on() function when a div is clicked, but not when a child of that div is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176099/jquery-on-function-when-a-div-is-clicked-but-not-when-a-child-of-that-div-i)

```
$(oTrPlanning).prev().children('td').each(function () {
    this.onclick = setCountClick;
});
```

On click of TD `setCountClick()` is called but TD also contains a `Textbox`:

```
<td> 
    <input class="Input-InlineFilter" id="TextFirst"  type="text" value="">
</td>
```

So, when I start typing something on `Textbox`, `setCountClick()` is again called.
I want to call `setCountClick()` when TD is clicked, but not `Textbox`.

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa. Why are you binding the `click` that way? Why not `$(oTrPlanning).prev().on('click', 'td', setCountClick)`?

Comment: I'm just gonna take a stab at this, but would onclick="return false;" in the textbox prevent that?

Comment: @Mathletics will do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The click event bubbles up the DOM from the `textbox` to the `td`, all the way to `body`. If you don't want `textbox` clicks to trigger the `td` click handler, you need to stop the bubbling:

```
$('#TextFirst').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropogation();
});
```

[Documentation for stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation)

To expand, you should be taking advantage of this bubbling to only bind **one** event handler for all `td`s:

```
// bind one handler to all tds
$(oTrPlanning).prev().on('click', 'td', function (e) {
    // ensure the clicked element is a TD
    if (this.nodeName === 'TD') {
        setCountClick(e);
    }
});
```

[Documentation for nodeName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeName)

Be aware that if you are relying on the `this` operator anywhere inside of `setCountClick`, it may no longer work as expected. To fix that you would need to look into using `$.proxy` or `bind` when you call `setCountClick`:

```
setCountClick.bind(this)(e);
```

`bind` returns a new function that uses the argument you pass as the `this` parameter inside the new function. Then you execute that function and pass it your regular parameters.

[Documentation for bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Why add another binding when you could just inspect the target in the bound handler on the parent?

Comment: This is now using the first `click` to set the click handler; I thought the OP wanted to actually fire the handler on click?

Comment: @Mathletics thanks, missed that.

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'on' ?

Comment: @Yogesh if you are using old versions of jQuery, try using `delegate` instead of `on`.

Comment: @jbabey I am using 'this' inside setCountClick. can you tell me more about $.proxy or bind. I am unaware of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that events are propagated from children to parents. You can bind like this:

```
$(oTrPlanning).prev().on('click', 'td', setCountClick);
```

Your method `setCountClick` will receive the `event` as its first argument, which you can inspect like so:

```
function setCountClick(event) {  
   // make sure the click was on a TD and not something else
   if ($(event.target).is('td')) {
        // you've hit a TD, run your code here
   }

}
```