# How to restore browser default behavior for an event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a web page (using HTML5/javascript) using divs to define the layout.

As I have a handful of elements that I want to be able to drag and do not want text selected during this process, I have disabled the `selectstart` and `onmousedown` events for the outermost container div, using:

```
document.getElementById("mapContainer").onselectstart = function(){return false;};
document.getElementById("mapContainer").onmousedown = function(){return false;};
```

However, I also have a text box within the layout that I need to be able to select and write in for searching purposes.  I have found numerous topics on how to disable browser default behavior for an event, but nothing concrete about how to restore the default behavior.  I can if need be, but I would like to avoid significant re-writes to the script.  Thus, I was wondering if there is a "restoreDefault" type function/setting that I could apply to just the text box.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, IMO. It sounds like you are trying to prevent the `onselectstart` event from bubbling up from child elements to the parent `mapContainer`, making it a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14176099/7469).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `addEventLsitener` and `removeEventListener` for better access to your event listeners:

```
function fooBar(){
    return false;
}

document.getElementById('mapContainer').addEventListener('selectstart', fooBar);    // Start listening
document.getElementById('mapContainer').removeEventListener('selectstart', fooBar); // Stop lsitening
```

You can also remove the event listener you currently have like this:

```
document.getElementById('mapContainer').onmousemove = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if it starts in the textarea before disabling it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mapContainer">
  <h2>What what?</h2>
  <textarea id="ta">FOO BAR WORLD</textarea>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function testForElement(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var elem = e.srcElement || e.target;
      return elem && elem.id==="ta";
}

var myDiv = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
myDiv.onselectstart = testForElement;
myDiv.onmousedown = testForElement;
```

**Example**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bVzA9/1/)